# How to disallow IP-based HTTP URL accesses to an Nginx webserver?

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, http

For example, my server is at Internet-accessible IPv4 address `192.0.2.4`. The associated DNS name is `my-website.example`.

I would like to block an HTTP client that attempts to access `https://192.0.2.4/`. I would like to allow a client that accesses `https://my-website.example`.

So for example,

```shell
$ curl -v http://192.0.2.4/
```

might print `HTTP/1.1 500` (or perhaps does not reply at all).

```shell
$ curl -v http://my-website.example/
```

would print `HTTP/1.1 200`.

How can I do that using nginx?

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty straight forward, simply edit the sites-enabled configuration file and configure it to return a 404 for an error page or 444 if you want to close the connection entirely.

```
server {
  listen 80 my-website.example;
  listen [::]:80 my-website.example;
  server_name _;

  return 444;
}
```

That's an example for you, the pertinent piece is the custom domain you want it to hit and killing the connection through the return parameter.

Update 1: I've edited `server_name ";` to `server_name _;` as it appears to be responsible for config errors on some systems.

Update 2: If you want to do this with HTTPS, a sample config can be found below.

```
server {
  listen 80 my-website.example;
  listen [::]:80 my-website.example;

 ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;

  listen 443 my-website.example;
  listen [::]:443 my-website.example;
  ssl_reject_handshake on;

  server_name _;
  return 444;
}
```

I've also considered that some systems may not be able to use the 444 rejection code, if you'd like to change that to something more well known you can use a 404. See the example below:

```
 if ($host != "my-website.example") {
  return 404;
 }
```

Comment: Also you can add a return 301/302 to redirecto to FQDN. It's optional

Comment: Thanks @SYNStealth . However, this did not work in my case. HTTP 444 was returned in _all_ cases (`http://my-website.example` and `http://192.0.2.4`).  Whereas, I wanted a normal HTTP 200 when the accessing `http://my-website.example`.

Comment: I see a possible issue with the example config. Try: `server_name _;` instead of `server_name "";` as I've suggested on the fourth line for you.

Comment: I've updated the answer to also provide SSL and a 404 alternative to the 444 if your server is still unhappy with it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your default vhost so that it returns for example 444 for all requests that don't match an existing vhost:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    return 444;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;

    # Rest of vhost config
}
```

You also need corresponding blocks for your HTTPS.

The default vhost might be already set up in the default configuration. You might need to edit that instead.

Comment: For HTTPs if the subject name(s) in your certificate is not (or does not include) the address, all connnection attempts will fail at the SSL/TLS level before sending any request nginx needs to be configured to reject. Most public CAs won't ever issue a cert for an address, but some will sometimes; a private or selfsigned cert technically _can_ contain the address but usually you have enough control or input to prevent it.

Comment: With TLS, nginx inspects the TLS ClientHello SNI field, which contains the virtual host name client tries to connect to. This allows nginx to select the proper virtual host block depending on the hostname. The fact that the certificate is not valid from client's point of view does not prevent nginx from sending a certificate to the client, which is configured in the virtual host.